# MySQL query (Not Like statement)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that shows car reservation, and I have two buttons to filter reservation between the dates. My problem here is that when I select the filter, my query of filtering out Cars that does not have reservations in the dates are not too working because cars usually have multiple reservations in different dates. 
Search between Day 4 - 6
Car 1 Day 1, Day 4
Car 2 Day 2, Day 5

It will show both car 1 and car 2.

```
public function search_free_boat($keyword, $fromdate, $todate){

    $where = 'where (boat_data.boat_name NOT LIKE reservation_data.boatname AND "fromdate > '%".$keyword."%' OR todate < '%".$keyword."%' OR fromdate IS NULL OR todate IS NULL")';
    $order = "id DESC";
    if(!empty($sort_field))
        $order = $sort_field." ".$sort_order;
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * , boat_data.boat_name as freeboat, reservation_data.boatname as busyboat FROM boat_data LEFT JOIN reservation_data ON boat_data.boat_name =reservation_data.boatname ".$where." GROUP BY boat_name ORDER BY boat_name ");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I am not sure if I should use Distinct (if this will work). What I want is that it shows cars that do not match with any reservation time.

Comment: Could you post how your dates are stored in your database?

Comment: there are two columns, which is fromdate and todate...they are two different columns

Comment: Could you post some example data from those columns?